# Can a matrix in a vector space be a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Taking the definition of a vector space "A vector space (also called a linear space) is a set of objects called vectors, which may be added together and multiplied ("scaled") by numbers, called scalars." So, for example:

Let S be the space of all $2 \times 2$ matrices. So the objects from the vector space S that we call vectors are the $2 \times 2$ matrices.

My question is: matrices are vectors?

Comment: Yes, $2\times 2$ matrices can be viewed as vectors $(a, b,c,d)$ in $4$-dimensional space.

Comment: Yes. A vector is an element of a vector space. Matrices form a vector space. Hence any matrix *can be regarded as a vector* in the vector space of matrices. In mathematics it is essential to always state the context, when talking about objects, because you can often view them from different perspectives…

Comment: So, why some people defines vectors as "A vector is an object that has both a magnitude and a direction." I mean, matrices don't have magnitude or direction, or do they? And functions? Do they have magnitude and direction?

Comment: "has a magnitude" should really be replaced by "can be scaled". Something with a magnitude can simply be scaled by scaling its magnitude, but a magnitude is not needed for scaling. The "magnitude and direction" definition is really just a handwavey way to impart an intuition about a very special case of vectors, namely those in Euclidean space. You should discard that "definition" once you start learning linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of two n by m matrices is again an n by m matrix.  The matrix with all entries 0 is the additive identity and if matrix B is formed by multiplying every entry of matrix A is the additive inverse of A.  Multiplying each entry of an n by m matrix by a number, a, is again an n by m matrix.